# 404 file or directory not found in wcf?

Tags: wcf, http-status-code-404

Why am I getting the `404 file or directory not found` issue in WCF?

I have a client system with two IPs, one is local and the other is global. I've published the files using the local IP.

I'm getting results but using the global IP I get the `404 file or directory not found` error.

What is causing this?

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that Windows Communication Foundation HTTP/Non-HTTP Activation is enabled for .Net framework in 'Windows features'.

To enable it, go to 'control panel' --> click 'Programs & Features'/'Add/Remove programs' --> click 'Turn Windows Feature on or off' --> from listing expand 'Microsoft .Net framework 3.5.1 (/your version)' --> check both 'Windows Communication Foundation HTTP Activation' & 'Windows Communication Foundation Non-HTTP Activation' --> click 'OK'.

I hope it was helpful.

Comment: For windows server: In the Add Features dialog, under.NET Framework 3.0 Features, select the .NET Framework 3.0. Under WCF Activation, select HTTP Activation. Click the Next button to install. Its under .Net 4.5 in Windows server 2012

Answer (score 0):

Check your wcf configuration. It maybe that your service is published to the local address only.

for example if you have a line that looks something like this:

```
<endpoint address="http://localhost/test" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCF4Configuration.IEchoService"/>
```

Note the **localhost**